# Compiler chooses functor over function with same name

Tags: c++, function, functor

Can someone please explain what rule determines that the compiler calls the functor `f` below instead of the function `f`?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    void operator()() { std::cout << "functor" << std::endl; }
};

void f() { std::cout << "function" << std::endl; }

int main()  
{
    A f;
    f();  // Output: functor
}
```

`A::operator()()` and `f()` are not overloads, so my guess is this happens outside of overload resolution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's due to name hiding. When you declare the `f` variable, it hides the `f` function. Any use of the name `f` in that scope will refer to the local variable rather than the function.

If you want to call the function `f`, then you could use the [scope resolution operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator):

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    void operator()() { std::cout << "functor" << std::endl; }
};

void f() { std::cout << "function" << std::endl; }

int main()  
{
    A f;
    ::f();  // Output: function
}
```